# Angular 5 app Server Request Error in Safari and IE11

Tags: javascript, angular, polyfills

I am working on an `Angular 5.2` app and it is not working properly on `IE11`, `Safari 5.7.1 (windows)` and `iPad`.

When my app initializes, it gets data from an API on the same server and creates a dynamic table using this API data. It is working fine in `chrome` and `firefox` but in `Safari`, `IE11` and `iPad`, it loads partially and dynamic content doesn't display as it is unable to communicate to the server and fetch `API` data.

I looked for the possible solutions on the internet and also tried to modify polyfill.js as instructed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46291102/angular-4-app-not-working-on-ie11-and-edge), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824362/angular-5-app-not-working-in-ios8-browserstack) and similar questions but it is not working in my case.

even I can see my login form, but login is also not working as cannot communicate to `API` server in `safari` and `IE11`.

**pollyfills.ts**

```
// This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
// You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/client/shim';
import 'whatwg-fetch'
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';

// If you need to support the browsers/features below, uncomment the import
// and run `npm install import-name-here';
// Learn more in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html

// Needed for: IE9
 import 'classlist.js';

// Animations
// Needed for: All but Chrome and Firefox, Not supported in IE9
 import 'web-animations-js';

// Date, currency, decimal and percent pipes
// Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE11 and Safari 10
import 'intl';

// NgClass on SVG elements
// Needed for: IE10, IE11
import 'classlist.js';
```

my service method to get data:

```
readServices(){
    let data:any = {server_status_code:this.server_status_code}
    let body = prepareData(data);
    return this._http.post(this.URL,body);
  }
```

**Error in Safari console:**

```
ERROR 
  Response
    _body: XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent
    headers: Headers
    line: 20093
    ok: false
    sourceId: 2123356416
    sourceURL: "http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js"
    status: 0
    statusText: ""
    type: 3
    url: null
__proto__: Response type: 3
url: null
__proto__: Response
constructor: function Response(responseOptions) {
toString: function () {
__proto__: Body
```

Please provide appropriate guidance. Thanks.

Comment: same issue for me.